# Laravel does not validate input data before insertion

Tags: php, mysql, backend, laravel-10

I encountered an error when the user registers, everything is ok and works perfectly, but when the user registers again with the same previous data, it shows this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '123456789' for key 'users.users_phone_unique'

and i have no ideo what is wrong in these codes
i'm using laravel 10

this is my register controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:11'],
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

this is my user.php

```
namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'phone',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'phone',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
}
```

this is my create user table migration

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('phone')->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

Comment: You require phone number to be unique and sign up fails when phone number is not unique. Are you asking why you don't get a friendly message, or it all comes as a surprise?

Comment: i'm looking for a friendly message but it does not show a message to user

Comment: Set a [Unique (Database)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique) validation rule for the column. (Maybe make the `name` column unique too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you're not validating the uniqueness of the phone number, hence the data is "passed down" to the DB level, and then it fails because of the violated `unique` constraint.

You should add a `unique` validation rule in your `RegisterController` in order to fail as soon as the form is sent.

For example:

```
'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:11','unique:users']
```

Comment: it fixed my problem but how should i show a friendly message to user that this account exist?

Comment: If you read the documentation, there's a [section](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) that explains exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna suggest a different approach which is considered to be a better practice for validation.

1. run `php artisan make:request CreateUserRequest`, the `CreateUserRequest` file will be created in `/app/Http/Requests` directory.
2. edit the file according to your needs, for example:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:11','unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        /**
         * or if you want to accept complex passwords add `use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;`
         * on top of the `CreateUserRequest` and then use the following rule instead
         */
        'password' => [
            'required', 'confirmed', 
            Password::min(8)->letters()->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols()
        ],
    ];
}
```

3. for a custom message in case of a failed validation you can add the following method to your `CreateUserRequest` class:

```
/**
 * Set proper error messages for failed validations
 *
 * @return array<string>
 */
public function messages() {
    return [
        'password.required' => 'my friendly message to the user',
    ];
}
```

You need to modify your controller accordingly, for more information take a look at [Form Validation Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation).